# Can hook beforeUpdate/afterUpdate modify the value?

Tags: strongloop, loopbackjs

I have model call "point", I want to update field "updated" on point in every action update. So, I make hook boforeUpdate to modify updated with new Date(). In result callback is true, and updated fied is a new datetime. But not updated on db, the field still old datetime. 
My code:

```
var app = require('../../../server.js'),
point = app.models.point;

point.beforeUpdate = function(next) {
  var app = this;
  app.updated = new Date();
  next();
}
```

Comment: What method do you call to update the instance? save, updateAttributes?

Comment: I use "Postman" (chrome-extension) to PUT point/:id and create beforeUpdate hook in my point model.

Answer (score 1):

`beforeUpdate` callback takes two parameters: a callback (which is `next` in your example) and an object (your point instance)

```
var app = require('../../../server.js'),
point = app.models.point;

point.beforeUpdate = function(next, pt) {
  pt.updated = new Date();
  next();
}
```

Assuming that your code lies in `app/models/point.js` it can be simplified to:

```
module.exports = function(Point) {
  Point.beforeUpdate = function(next, point) {
    point.updated = new Date();
    next();
  }
};
```